GLPK with Pyomo
I am using pycharm and I want to use glpk solver with pyomo. Can anyone please help me resolve this error.
I tried pip install glpk But I am getting error
Problem with pip.

ERROR: Failed building wheel for glpk
Failed to build glpk
ERROR: Could not build wheels for glpk, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Then i followed this step;
pip install libglpk-dev  

got this error

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libglpk-dev (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for libglpk-dev

I am using pycharm and I want to use glpk solver with pyomo. Can anyone please help me resolve this error.
I tried the steps given in this forum.

You can take a look at this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61054203/cant-install-libpq-dev
